# How would be this design about access data?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, repository, repository-pattern

I need to implement a class called Foo where I need to `Get` and `Save` through a data access.

I can imagine I need to classes, one is to access, get and save data from an XmlFile, and another is the service which returns objects through like queries (`GetFooById, GetFooByLevel`, ...), that's my first though. That's the reason why I want to clarify this design and what things I need to separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with the repository pattern.
You can do something like this

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
   void Save(Foo);
   Foo GetById(int id);
   Foo GetByLevel(int level) 
}

 public class FooXmlRepository:IFooRepository
  {
       //implementation
   }

  IFooRepository repo= new FooXmlRepository(); //or via your favorite DI container
```

In this way the Foo object is decoupled by the storage concerns. And later if you want to use a db instead of xml, just write another implementation. The app will be using the interface so you don't have to change anything else that the assignment of 'repo'.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you're interfacing database I'd go with one repository for all the related.
In case of XML - as I think you have -
XML load/save could be made part of the Foo - e.g. `static Foo Parse(string)` and `string ToXML()` or something similar. That allows you to have a more 'fluent' loading/saving (and if you have more objects hierarchy etc. which is often the case with XML - with Db/relational data things are more 'flat' and then loading/saving is really about iterating the records. In case of XML is often more about walking through the hierarchy with nodes etc.).  Or you could separate into an extensions class - e.g. `Get(this Foo, string xml)`.
In my opinion, I consider xml get/save more like a serialization (but depends on your objects, hierarchy, overall structure).
And then you can build a repository fore querying around that.
If your 'Foo' is not or might not stick to XML in the future - then separate.